# the proof of faithfully flat module is faithful

Tags: ring-theory, modules, flatness

I know faithful and flat module is not always faithfully flat.
For example $\mathbb Q \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z=0$ implies $\mathbb Q$ is not faithfully flat as $\mathbb Z$-module unless it is faithful and flat as $\mathbb Z$-module.

But is the converse true?

I want to know the proof of

> faithfully flat module is faithful and flat（flatness is obvious）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the annihilator $I$ of a flat module $M$ and the commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> I\otimes_R M @>>> R\otimes_R M @>>> R/I\otimes_R M @>>> 0 \\
@. @VfVV @VgVV @VhVV \\
0 @>>> IM @>>> M @>>> M/IM @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
The obvious morphisms $g$ and $h$ are isomorphisms even if $M$ is not flat; if $M$ is flat, also $f$ is an isomorphism. Since $IM=0$ by definition, we have $I\otimes_RM=0$ and, if $M$ is also faithfully flat, this implies $I=0$.